# Ubuntu 18.04 desktop share show connection icon when somebody connected over VNC till connection active

Tags: 18.04, icons, remote-desktop, vnc

In Ubuntu 18.04 when desktop sharing is enabled and somebody connects over VNC. For the connection establishment, there is a notification received. 
But it is not possible to see that when the connection is closed (no notification) and it would be nice to display an icon with active VNC connections.
It was like this in 16.04.

Comment: Hi Csita, unfortunately, we cannot choose here what can be added into Gnome VNC source code, you should log this request to Ubuntu instead.